# Mac VSCode 1.64, 1.61 Extension host terminated unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

Mac OSX: `10.15.7`
VSCode: `1.64.2` and then tried downgrading to 1.61.2

Been having this issue:
[image]

When Opening developer tools, this is what i find:
[image]

To bypass this problem this is what i have done but to no success:

1. Cleared Editors History
2. Disabled all extensions
3. Deleted all extensions
4. Completely removed VSCode from mac
5. Restarted/rebooted several times
6. Ensured I had "Help: Start Extension Bisect"
7. Upgraded node version to `16.14.0`
8. Cleared more space on my machine

All this I did to no avail.

Please help how to solve this issue. I cannot get vscode back on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question.. I had an automated script using crontab to kill node instances.
Learned this by knowing about the `SIGTERM`

Posted the answer here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143623